Compiler asking to declare MyLinkedList as abstract and leads MyLinkedListExtra to not being able to instantiate. Does MyList Interface need work?
When I compile I get an error stating that MyLinkedList should be declared abstract or include a get() in MyList interface. If I declare MyLinkedList as abstract then I have to declare MyLinkedListExtra as abstract too(compiler asks of that once I satisfy declaring MyLinkedList as abstract) which leads to it not being able to instantiate. However, they should not be abstract. I'm at a bit of a loss and hope it's just a typo as other similar posts.
Thank you and appreciate the help in advance.
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        String[] names = { "Tom", "Susan", "Kim", "George", "Peter",
                "Jean", "George", "Jane", "Denise", "Jenny", "Susan", "Kathy", "Jane" };
        MyList<String> list = new MyLinkedListExtra<>(names);

        System.out.println(list);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        String name = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter an index: ");
        int index = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(name + " is in the list? " + list.contains(name));
        System.out.println("name at index " + index + " is " + list.get(index));
        System.out.println(name + " is at index " + list.indexOf(name));
        System.out.println(name + " is at last index " + list.lastIndexOf(name));
        list.set(index, name);
        System.out.println("Updated list: " + list);
    }

    // MyList interface
    public interface MyList<E> extends java.util.Collection<E> {
        public void add(int index, E e);

        public E get(int index);

        public int indexOf(Object e);

        public int lastIndexOf(Object e);

        public E remove(int index);

        public E set(int index, E e);

        @Override
        public default boolean add(E e) {
            add(size(), e);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public default boolean isEmpty() {
            return size() == 0;
        }

        @Override
        public default boolean remove(Object e) {
            int index = indexOf(e);
            if (index >= 0) {
                remove(index);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public int size();
    }

    // MyLinkedList class

                public class MyLinkedList<E> implements MyList<E> {
                protected Node<E> head, tail;
                protected int size = 0; // Number of elements in the list

        /** Create an empty list */
        public MyLinkedList() {
        }

        @Override
        public void add(int index, E e) {
            if (index == 0) {
                addFirst(e);
            } else if (index >= size) {
                addLast(e);
            } else {
                Node<E> current = head;
                for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
                    current = current.next;
                }
                Node<E> temp = current.next;
                current.next = new Node<>(e);
                (current.next).next = temp;
                size++;
            }
        }

        public void addFirst(E e) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e);
            newNode.next = head;
            head = newNode;
            size++;
            if (tail == null) {
                tail = head;
            }
        }

        public void addLast(E e) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(e);
            if (tail == null) {
                head = tail = newNode;
            } else {
                tail.next = newNode;
                tail = tail.next;
            }
            size++;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        protected static class Node<E> {
            E element;
            Node<E> next;

            public Node(E element) {
                this.element = element;
            }
        }
    }

    // MyLinkedListExtra class
            public class MyLinkedListExtra<E> extends MyLinkedList<E> {

        /** Create an empty list */
        public MyLinkedListExtra() {
            super();
        }

        /** Create a list from an array of objects */
        public MyLinkedListExtra(E[] objects) {
            super();
            for (E object : objects) {
                this.add(object);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            Node<E> current = head;
            while (current != null) {
                if (current.element.equals(o)) {
                    return true;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds");
            }

            Node<E> current = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            return current.element;
        }

        @Override
        public int indexOf(Object o) {
            Node<E> current = head;
            int index = 0;
            while (current != null) {
                if (current.element.equals(o)) {
                    return index;
                }
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
            Node<E> current = head;
            int index = 0;
            int lastIndex = -1;

            while (current != null) {
                if (current.element.equals(o)) {
                    lastIndex = index;
                }
                current = current.next;
                index++;
            }
            return lastIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public E set(int index, E e) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds");
            }

            Node<E> current = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                current = current.next;
            }

            E oldElement = current.element;
            current.element = e;
            return oldElement;
        }
    }
}


"If I declare MyLinkedList as abstract then I have to declare MyLinkedListExtra as abstract" - Why do you think so?

Note that you should use three backticks, not apostrophes, for code. Please always use the preview to check that your code is formatted correctly before posting.

Hello hotsriracha, When a class inherits from an abstract class, or implements an interface, a "contract" is created in which you can choose two paths, either you implement all the abstract methods of the class you inherit from (or the methods of the interface) or you declare the class abstract, letting the one that inherits it do so.

order for a class to be concrete (non-abstract) it has to implement all the methods of any interfaces it claims to implement, and any abstract methods of the superclass.
In this case, the first errors javac reported to me were:

MyLinkedList can't be a concrete class because it doesn't implement set(int, E) declared in MyList<E>
MyLinkedListExtra can't be a concrete class because it doesn't implement remove(int) declared in MyList<E>

... and various other members are missing too.
You can't just implement some of the methods. You've got to implement all of them. In order to make MyLinkedList<E> compile as a non-abstract class, I had to provide implementations of:

public void clear()
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> other)
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> other)
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> other)
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> other)
public E set(int index, E e)
public E get(int index)
public E remove(int index)
public int lastIndexOf(Object e)
public int indexOf(Object e)
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array)
public Object[] toArray()
public Iterator<E> iterator()
public boolean contains(Object o)

In order to implement MyList<E>, which extends Collection<E>, you have to implement all of those methods.

I sincerely appreciate your time and response. This makes a lot of sense and will work on implementing all missing methods. I take there is no work around this then? e.g Override?

There's no work around because it's the way things are supposed to work.  That said, you might find it helps to start by extending AbstractList.

Specifically, java.util.AbstractList will provide many of these functions with default implementations.
